# Meaning of Swimming their horses

Tags: meaning

> If the weather keeps up, they'll be **swimming their horses** round the
>   track.

What is the meaning of swimming their horses here?

Comment: Please read [*Why you should cite your source*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) on meta, and then update your question with a note saying where you found this sentence.

Answer (score 16):

You haven't provided context, so this is what I can say -

- There's a horse race.
- The weather is bad because it's raining heavily.
- Since it's raining heavily, it's likely to flood.

This is a **Hyperbole**, because they are not likely to make their horses swim around the track.

Answer (score 10):

This is a play on words.

"Running their horses" is a common phrase used in descriptions of horse racing.  For example, when the owner of a horse puts the horse in a race, he is "running his horse".

The author is humorously suggesting that "if the weather keeps up", the race track will become either a mud pit or a lake.  At that point, the only way that the jockeys will be able to have a race will be by "swimming their horses round the track."